# struct declared in abstract class and initialiced in derived class not visible when instanced

Tags: c#, struct, visibility, derived-class

I've been looking for this question but hadn't have no luck, I hope it isn't repeated.
I have one abstract class.

```
public abstract class IFDB
{
     public struct Estructura_TablaCuentasBancarias
    {
        public string NombreTabla;
        public string NumeroDeCuenta;
        public string Entidad;
        public string DNIPropietario;

        public Estructura_TablaCuentasBancarias(string NombreTabla, string NumeroDeCuenta, string Entidad, string DNIPropietario)
        {
            this.NombreTabla = NombreTabla;
            this.NumeroDeCuenta = NumeroDeCuenta;
            this.Entidad = Entidad;
            this.DNIPropietario = DNIPropietario;
        }
    }
```

}

And the derived class:

```
class CntrDBSQLSRVCompac: IFDB
{
     public readonly Estructura_TablaCuentasBancarias TablaCuentasBancarias =
        new Estructura_TablaCuentasBancarias("CuentasBancarias", "Numero De Cuenta", "Entidad", "DNI Propietario");
```

In the program I have done the instance:

```
protected IFDB ClsCntrlDB;
...

ClsCntrlDB = new CntrDBSQLSRVCompac();
```

But when trying to use the estructure "TablaCuentasBancarias" it's not on the list of possible functions/vars. 
If the instance and initialization of the structure is done in the IFDB class it works perfectly but, I want to make the IFDB class an interface.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: It is entirely unclear what issue you are having. Consider revising your question.

Comment: Then how its possible for people to response this question? I don't care about points, I thank the people that has tried to help me (not like you) with a problem that has blocked me... Sometimes the most stupid problems are the worst.

Comment: I 'm not sure where you got the negative attitude from. I simply made a comment intended to help you find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works fine for me, so maybe you have some other issue.

```
abstract class FooBase
{
    public struct Bar
    {

    }
}

class Foo : FooBase
{
    public readonly Bar BarInstance = new Bar();
}

class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var bar = foo.BarInstance; //works fine
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1368116: the image shows there is an error in IFDB.cs, it says something about virtual keyword

Comment: Ok, here you have an image compiled, with the same problem and all the code. Sorry if the previous image causes confusion: [link](http://postimage.org/image/pfjam0iw5/full/)

Comment: @user1368116: ok, your problem is that ClsCntrlDB is of type IFDB which doesn't expose the field you're looking for. You should declare ClsCntrlDB as CntrDBSQLSRVCompac.

Comment: I see the point now, but your solution has a big problem. If I'm planning to  use an interface the logical thing to do is declare the instance ClsCntrlDB as IFDB, in other case making an interface will be of no sense. Thank you.

Comment: @user1368116: your question was "What I'm doing wrong?", you also said "I'm going to turn it to an interface but thats not the question now". Maybe you should ask another question and state your current problem.

Comment: OK, I think its fair! With the solution another question came and perhaps I'm messing things. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`Estructura_TablaCuentasBancarias` is a [nested structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx). In order to make `IFDB` in interface you'll need to extract the nested struct from `IFDB`

```
public interface IFDB
{
    Estructura_TablaCuentasBancarias Foo { get; set; }

    // other properties/functions from the IFDB class
}

public struct Estructura_TablaCuentasBancarias
{
    // struct declaration
}
```

Comment: As i have said before, If the instance and initialization of the structure is done in the IFDB class it works perfectly. But I don't want that, because I want to turn this class (IFDB) into an interface. So I want to do the instance and declaration in the derived class (CntrDBSQLSRVCompac). Thank you for your response.

Comment: I'm out of time for the moment, as soon as I can I'll have a look. Thank you.